# The word 'Any tooth or any teeth"

Tags: grammar

Should we ask: do your have any "loose tooth" or "loose teeth"?

Comment: This question is more suitable for our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), although I suppose you could first look up the word [**teeth**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teeth) in a dictionary and explain why you still have a doubt on which word to use.

Answer (score 2):

Arvind Haran is correct.

If you were asking about any one tooth (singular), you would ask:

> Do you have a loose tooth?

Using the article "a" to indicate a singular tooth, or you might ask:

> Is your front tooth loose?

However, if you were asking more generally about whether there are loose teeth (plural) in one's mouth, you would ask:

> Do you have any loose teeth?

You would not use the singular article "a" with the plural word "teeth", just as you would not use the word "any" with the singular word "tooth".

This is all due to the fact that tooth is a countable noun, i.e. there is a singular and a plural form of the noun.

The Capital Community College Foundation has published a very informative webpage about [Count and non-Count Nouns](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/noncount.htm), which you should read if you have difficulty telling the difference between countable and non-countable nouns.

To learn which articles go with countable nouns and which articles go with un-countable nouns, this polseguera.com webpage has an online lesson (unit) on [Articles](http://www.polseguera.com/freegrammar/articles.htm), and if you find the exercises on this page useful, there are links to more lessons (units) at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it goes as "Do you have any loose teeth?", since the question accommodates the possibility of there being more than one loose tooth.